# Loading video and image from local storage into Google ChromeCast android

Tags: android, chromecast

How to set local video URI/Path/File to MediaInfo.Builder() of chromecast ? Also, anyone could please help me with a code snippet on how to load image and video locally from android storage and cast it to the google chrome cast ? 
Read other questions too but over there it has been mentioned to create a local server on app. If really we need to do this then how to implement this ? I am using code available on https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android but over there video is fetched and played from url. I want to load video from local storage also i want to show images also.

Updated:
Now I have a created a local server using "NanoHttpD" but is unable to get the url of selected local file. Below is my Acitivities code snippet:

```
public class VideoBrowserFragment extends Fragment implements VideoListAdapter.ItemClickListener,
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<MediaInfo>> {

    private static final String TAG = "zz VideoBrowserFragment";
    private static final int REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO = 123;
    private static final String CATALOG_URL =
            "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/CastVideos/f.json";
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private VideoListAdapter mAdapter;
    private View mEmptyView;
    private View mLoadingView;
    private VideoCastManager mCastManager;
    private VideoCastConsumerImpl mCastConsumer;
    private View btnLocalVideo;
    LocalServer server;
    String chosenExt = "";
    String localFileName = "";
    String localFilePath = "";
    String formatedIpAddress = "";
    Uri selectedImageUri;

    public VideoBrowserFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "VideoBrowserFragment onCreateView", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "VideoBrowserFragment onCreateView");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_browser_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "VideoBrowserFragment onViewCreated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "VideoBrowserFragment onViewCreated");

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
        mEmptyView = getView().findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        mLoadingView = getView().findViewById(R.id.progress_indicator);
        btnLocalVideo = getView().findViewById(R.id.btnLocalVideo);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mAdapter = new VideoListAdapter(this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        mCastManager = VideoCastManager.getInstance();
        mCastConsumer = new VideoCastConsumerImpl() {
            @Override
            public void onConnected() {
                super.onConnected();
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnected() {
                super.onDisconnected();
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        mCastManager.addVideoCastConsumer(mCastConsumer);


//fetch local video
        btnLocalVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("video/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO);


            }
        });
    }


    //get data of locally fetched videos....
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO) {
                 selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sending local video data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                MediaMetadata movieMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);

                movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE, "Local Subtitle");
                movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, "Local Video is playing");

                JSONObject jsonObj = null;
                try {
                    jsonObj = new JSONObject();
                    jsonObj.put("description", "Sample Descrioption over here");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to add description to the json object", e);
                }
                String filePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                chosenExt = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                startLocalServer();
                String localUrl = formatedIpAddress + localFilePath;
                Log.d(TAG, "MediaInfo urlLocal: " + localUrl);
                MediaInfo item = new MediaInfo.Builder(localUrl)
                        .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                        .setContentType("video/mp4")
                        .setMetadata(movieMetadata)
                        .setStreamDuration(333 * 1000)
                        .build();
                Log.d(TAG, "VideoBrowserFragment itemClicked media :" + Utils.mediaInfoToBundle(item));

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LocalPlayerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("media", Utils.mediaInfoToBundle(item));
                intent.putExtra("shouldStart", false);
                intent.putExtra("isLocal", true);
                intent.putExtra("videoUri", selectedImageUri.toString());
               /* Pair<View, String> imagePair = Pair
                        .create((View) viewHolder.getImageView(), transitionName);*/
                ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat
                        .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity());
                ActivityCompat.startActivity(getActivity(), intent, options.toBundle());

            }
        }
    }


    //get path of video fetched...
    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        Log.d(TAG, "uri is " + uri);
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri, proj, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //int column_index1 = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);//Instead of "MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA" can be used "_data"
            Uri filePathUri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(column_index));
            String file_name = filePathUri.getLastPathSegment().toString();
            String file_path = filePathUri.getPath();
            localFileName = file_name;
            localFilePath = file_path;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "File Name & PATH are:" + file_name + "\n" + file_path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("zz fileData: ", "fp: " + file_path + " :and: fn: " + file_name);
        }
        String result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "VideoBrowserFragment onDetach", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "VideoBrowserFragment onDetach");
        mCastManager.removeVideoCastConsumer(mCastConsumer);
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void itemClicked(View view, MediaInfo item, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "VideoBrowserFragment itemClicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "VideoBrowserFragment itemClicked");

        if (view instanceof ImageButton) {
            Log.d(TAG, "menu was clicked");
            com.scriptlanes.cast2.utils.Utils.showQueuePopup(getActivity(), view, item);
        } else {
            String transitionName = getString(R.string.transition_image);
            VideoListAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder =
                    (VideoListAdapter.ViewHolder) mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForPosition(position);
            Pair<View, String> imagePair = Pair
                    .create((View) viewHolder.getImageView(), transitionName);
            ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat
                    .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), imagePair);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LocalPlayerActivity.class);
            Log.d(TAG, "VideoBrowserFragment itemClicked media :" + Utils.mediaInfoToBundle(item));

            intent.putExtra("media", Utils.mediaInfoToBundle(item));
            intent.putExtra("shouldStart", false);
            //isUrl=true, isLocal=false
            intent.putExtra("isLocal", false);
            ActivityCompat.startActivity(getActivity(), intent, options.toBundle());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<List<MediaInfo>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "VideoBrowserFragment onCreateLoader", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "VideoBrowserFragment onCreateLoader");

        return new VideoItemLoader(getActivity(), CATALOG_URL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<MediaInfo>> loader, List<MediaInfo> data) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "VideoBrowserFragment onLoadFinished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "VideoBrowserFragment onLoadFinished");
        mAdapter.setData(data);
        mLoadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mEmptyView.setVisibility(null == data || data.isEmpty() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<MediaInfo>> loader) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "VideoBrowserFragment onLoaderReset", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "VideoBrowserFragment onLoaderReset");
        mAdapter.setData(null);
    }



    /*temp code nanohttpd*/


    public class LocalServer extends NanoHTTPD {

        private  final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(LocalServer.class.getName());

        public  void main(String[] args) {
            ServerRunner.run(LocalServer.class);
        }
        public LocalServer() {
            super(3000);
            Log.d("zz nanaHttpd: ", "STARTED");

        }

       @Override
        public Response serve(String uri, Method method, Map<String, String> header, Map<String, String> parameters, Map<String, String> files) {
            //String mediasend = getExtension(chosenFile);

           Log.d("zz nanaHttpd:  ", "uri:  " + uri+" , method: "+method);
           FileInputStream fis = null;
           File file = new File(localFilePath);
           Log.e("Creando imputStream", "Size: ");
           try {
               fis = new FileInputStream(file);
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

            return new NanoHTTPD.Response(Response.Status.OK, "video/mp4", fis);
        }

    }

    private void startLocalServer() {
        server = new LocalServer();
        try {
            server.start();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.d("zz Httpd", "The server could not start.");
        }
        Log.d("zz Httpd", "Web server initialized.");
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        int ipAddress = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress();
        Log.d("zz Httpd IP U: ", ipAddress + "");
        String formatedIpAddress1 = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", (ipAddress & 0xff), (ipAddress >> 8 & 0xff),
                (ipAddress >> 16 & 0xff), (ipAddress >> 24 & 0xff));
        formatedIpAddress = "http://" + formatedIpAddress1 + ":" + server.getListeningPort();
        Log.d("zz Httpd IP: ", "Please access! " + formatedIpAddress);


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //server.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem ?

Comment: @Nasib No, not yet.

Comment: If you have solved the problem then can you please post the solution? We share the common scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As you have seen in other posts, you need to add an embedded web server to your app and expose your local content in that web server. Then you need to send the url of these local contents to your chromecast. There are a number of open source small embedded http servers that can be used if you don't want to build write your own tiny http server, you can google for such embedded solutions.

Comment: Thanks @Ali Naddaf....... Though i tried creating a local server through "NanoHttpD" but I am not getting how to pass the url of the selected video/image. I have done the following: (1) through intent opened a gallery for selecting a video file and then onActivityResult i got the uri of selected video . After that What exactly i have to do ?

Comment: Ali Naddaf i have updated my question by adding my whole acitvity code for you.. Please could you tell me a way to get the url of selected video file through "NanoHttpD" local server.

Comment: Suggest to refer https://github.com/KaustubhPatange/Android-Cast-Local-Sample

Answer (score 0):

Your are doing it right, Just put the selected url like this:

```
mediaMetadata.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse(http://192.168.0.XX:8080/video.mp4));
```